# Jquery mobile: ui-state=dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Am using JQuery mobile for a usermenu list, but it seems to save the pressed button link "ui-state=dialog" Which is disturbing the navigation when am using the back button on the webbrowser. How can i remove the "ui-state=dialog" which adds to the URL?

Example: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/

Try the first so called "basic popup", the saved URL which is: "ui-state=dialog" still appears in the broswer history.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the refresh problem, I use to intercept #&ui-state and similar on page creation and eventually redirect to a clean url:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate",function(){
    if(window.location.hash!=""){
        window.location.replace(window.location.origin+window.location.pathname);
    }
});
```

To avoid to insert the #&ui-state in browser history, it's possible to add data-history="false" to every popup:

```
<div data-history="false" data-role="popup" ...
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer `data-history="false"`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem: by using:

```
$( ".selector" ).popup({
  history: false
});

$(document).on("pageinit", function() 
{
     $( ".selector" ).popup({
       history: false
    });

});
```

More information:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#option-history

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is by assigning `data-history="false"` attribute in the markup:

```
<div data-history="false" data-role="popup" id="popup-1" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="b">
```