# jquery selector stop working problem cuz #&ui-state=dialog data-history="false" didnt work

Tags: php, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

the form works fine the first time 
after i submit the form the url gets #&ui-state=dialog and the 2 selectors will not open again till i reload the page
i did find [Jquery mobile: ui-state=dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142990/jquery-mobile-ui-state-dialog/64495512#64495512)
but    data-history="false" did not help 
all so tryd:

```
 $( ".selector" ).popup({
      history: false
    });
```

and few other things nothing seem to help

```
<body>    
            
            <form action="display2.php" method="get" data-history="false" data-history="false">
            
                   <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="ui-field-contain" data-history="false">
                <label for="select-choice-15" class="select">rooms:</label>
                <select  name="select-choice-15" id="select-choice-15" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="a" data-native-menu="false" >
                                    <option value="0">select</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                </select>
            </div>
                <div class="ui-field-contain" data-history="false">
                <label for="select-choice-16" class="select">up to:</label>
                <select  name="select-choice-16" id="select-choice-16" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="a" data-native-menu="false">
                                    <option value="0">select</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div> 
                    <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
       <div class="ui-grid-b ui-responsive">
        <div class="ui-block-a"><a onclick="location.href = 'display2.php'" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-arrow-l">rest</a></div>
    </div>
            <legend>by:</legend>
            <label for="textinput-f">sort:</label>
             <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="filter..." data-inset="true" > 
                    
                  <?php 
           
             while($cityobj=$citylist->fetch_object())
             {
                 $cityobj->city2=str_replace(' ', '_', $cityobj->city);
                 echo '<li><input type="checkbox" name="'.$cityobj->city2.'" id="'.$cityobj->city2.'">
                <label for="'.$cityobj->city2.'">'.$cityobj->city.'</label></li>'."\n";
             }
                $citylist->close();  
               
             ?>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
                    
                    <button type="submit"> apply</button>       
                    
            </form>
        </body>
```